# Stepper Motor Controller With Arduino

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, 74hc595

I have seen many tutorial of Multiplexing 74HC595 with led's Is it possible to control Stepper motor with 74HC595 ? And Recently i have found a board SSC-32 which control 32 servos, so is it possible to use it for controlling stepper motors.
As the project I am working on a Huge consisting of 100 stepper motor with accompanied Driver uln2003 to be controlled. It would be a Big help if anyone guide me to correct path How can I achieve it and arduino Uno will be the brain of the project.

Comment: No, 74HC595 is not for directly driving motors. You can use '595 as a serial-in-parallel-out digital output, but each motor needs something like an `H-Bridge` power transistor circuit. Start by looking at example of driving a single stepper motor first.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned Steppper motors are accompanied with uln2003 driver. My Aim is to have ateast two arduinos to control motors. Something like nesting '595's to get more pins for arduino and control.As of now its just an idea.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't take a bunch of 74HC595s and put a power buffer on the output. For bipolar steppers, you could drive two motors per 74HC595. This is not going to get you any kind of high-performance motion, but you can get basic movement out of it.

I would not use the ULN2003 for this though. You would be better served with a push-pull configuration that can drive the motor without a pull-up resistor. (the ULN2003 has an open-collector output)

A SN754410 would do a better job for you (2 motors per chip) and you can get even cheaper with bare transistors or transistor arrays, but that gets a bit more in depth.

Comment: To be precise I am trying to make
tangible.media.mit.edu/project/inform as project
They have used potentiometer and DC motor for positioning but this combination is costly as compared to stepper motor. SO basically I am trying to find a cheaper way to make it.

Comment: Maybe you could go super-cheap and start out with simple on/off solenoids..

Comment: Using solonoid does not give step movement either its full on or full closed and we have already managed to purchase stepper motor bulk

Comment: I understand what you want, and I've given you an answer that will work... If you want to get fancier or lazier, look at ST's integrated smart stepper controllers. You can probably get them for $5-7 each.

Comment: Thanks I'll look to it and get back to u soon and appericiate for ur answer